# No route matches error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error

> No route matches {:action=>"index",
>   :controller=>"module/admin/orders"}

when using following:

```
<%= form_tag({ :action => :index}, { :method => "get" }) do %>
```

My routes have this path:

```
admin_orders GET /new/admin/orders(.:format) module/admin/orders#index
```

I tried to run this code in `rails console` and it works without errors:

```
r.url_for :controller => 'module/admin/orders', :action=> :index, :id=>42
 => "http://domain.com/new/admin/orders?id=42"

r.url_for :controller => 'module/admin/orders', :action=> :index
 => "http://domain.com/new/admin/orders"
```

My application is using `Spree` and this controller inherits `Spree::Admin::ResourceController` class

Comment: `url_for` will return the formatted URL irrespective of the method.  The `form_tag` that you supplied is explicitly using `get`, so that's the route that would be searched for.  Have you verified that your route has `get` (not `post`) semantics?  You might attach the pertinent portion of your `rake routes`, as well.

Comment: I'm sure this path have 'get' semantics. Portion of rake routes is attached above and code that works in console

Comment: i think its because rails is trying to find this route in spree engine somehow

Comment: Try `<%= form_tag admin_orders_path, method: 'get' do %>`

Comment: Try `<%= form_tag({ :controller => "orders", :action => :index}, { :method => "get" }) do %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to put routes configuration in the same engine controller is using (For example Spree in this case):

`Spree::Core::Engine.add_routes do
    scope 'module/' do
      namespace :admin, as: 'module_admin' do
        resources :orders, controller: '/module/admin/orders',
                  only: [:edit, :index, :update]
      end
    end`

and use:

`<%= form_tag(module_admin_orders_path, method: :get) %>`

or use url helpers with engine prefix:

`<%= form_tag(main_app.admin_orders_path, method: :get) %>`

Answer (score 0):

User proper url helpers ass follows

```
<%= form_tag(admin_orders_path, method: :get) %>
```